# Django static throws Invalid block tag

Tags: django

I am trying to embed an ajax file into my django template. But it returns an error:

```
>>> Invalid block tag on line 134: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

What causes this error?

```
   {% block javascripts %}
       <script src="{% static 'js/model-scripts/sampleAjax.js' %}"></script>
   {% endblock javascripts %}
```

Here is my static declaration in the sites SETTINGS:

```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put at the start of the HTML file the code:

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: I forgot to insert that line. This solved the problem. Thank you.